# Export org-mode tables to LaTeX mathematics matrices?

Tags: org-mode, latex

Does anyone have a good way to produce LaTeX mathematics [matrices](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Mathematics#Matrices_and_arrays)  from org-mode tables?

I found this [thread](http://thread.gmane.org/gmane.emacs.orgmode/62570/focus=62685) but it doesn't seem to have a ready-made solution.

This gets me close.

```
#+LATEX: \begin{equation}
#+LATEX: \begin{matrix}
| a | b |
| c | d |
#+LATEX: \end{matrix}
#+LATEX: \end{equation}
```

which exports to:

```
\begin{equation}
\begin{matrix}
\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{ll}
a & b\\
c & d\\
\end{tabular}
\end{center}
\end{matrix}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

And I only have to take out the tabular and center directives.

Comment: Could you be more precise as to what you want? If you write a table in an org file and use the export to latex feature, you obtain a latex table. If you are looking for something integrated in latex documents, radio tables might be what you're looking for. http://orgmode.org/manual/Tables-in-arbitrary-syntax.html#Tables-in-arbitrary-syntax

Comment: Take a look at `(info "(org) LaTeX specific attributes")`. The following will change your environment: `#+attr_latex: :mode math :environment matrix`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Take a look at `(info "(org) LaTeX specific attributes")`. The following table attributes

```
#+attr_latex: :mode math :environment matrix
| a | b |
| c | d |
```

will export a LaTeX matrix in math mode:

```tex
\[
\begin{matrix}
 a & b \\
 c & d \\
\end{matrix}
\]
```

Comment: For the sake of completeness: If you wish to give your matrix a name, the way to go is inserting the corresponding string (e.g. "M =") as an argument to `:math-prefix` in the option list of the table. Figuring this out took me a while, so I hope this saves everyone else some time.